# Using "find" with regex-negation on Linux Server

Tags: regex, grep, find, regex-negation

I need to go thourgh all Apache logs for the last year and find if a certain php page (foobar.php) was ever visited from an external IP address.

So I need to find all lines in Apache .log and log.gz files which contains foobar.php but exclude visits from all LANs IPs (192.168.x.x).

Can find or grep command do that?

Comment: what is your try so far ?

Comment: not much, I understand that the searched line must be between two line breaks, it should contain foobar.php and does not contain local adresses, so that should be something like:  find -type f -exec grep -regex "[\/r\/n(?=.*foobar\.php*)(?!.*192\.168\.*)\/r\/n]"

Comment: That would be better if you add some lines of your log file in the question.

Comment: `find` is about finding files by name, size, date, and the like.  It doesn't care about said files' contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your logs are in Common Logs Format (CLF), something like this should work:

```
zgrep -v '^192\.168\.' access.log* | grep '/foobar\.php'
```

Comment: Interesting that you'd do the negative grep first, I'd have thought the intuitive thing would be to grep for foobar first and then remove the lines about that ip rather than the other way around. Given a file that's 1000 lines long where 50 contain foobar and 50 contain that IP with some intersecting subset that contains both then doing it your way has the first grep searching through 1000 lines and the 2nd searching through 950 (i.e. 1950 lines searched total) whereas if you reverse it the 2nd grep is only searching through 50 lines (i.e. 1050 lines searched total).

Comment: @EdMorton The point of doing it this way is being able to match `^192\.168\.` anchored at the beginning of line. The other way around you'd need to skip over the name of file (produced by the first `grep`), which may or may not be as simple as `access.log.3.gz`. _shrug_

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (untested) should do it:

```
find dir_where_logs_are -type f \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*.log.gz' \) -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    case $file in
        *.gz ) zgrep 'mypage\.php' "$file" ;;
        * ) grep 'mypage\.php' "$file" ;;
    esac
done |
grep -E -v '192\.168\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
```

The above assumes no newlines in your file names.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, I like this two, I accepted the first answer however as that is just smaller. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These two commands should search for `/mypage.php` in all uncompressed and compressed Apache access logs:

```
grep '/mypage\.php' access.log access.log.[0-9] | grep -v '192\.168\.[0-9.]\+'     
zcat access.log*.gz | grep '/mypage\.php' | grep -v '192\.168\.[0-9.]\+'
```

`grep -v` negates the regex match for `192\.168\.[0-9.]*`. `zcat` is like `cat` for gzip-compressedfiles.

**Edit**: As @EdMorton pointed out in the comments, `awk` might be a better tool for us to use:

```
awk '/\/mypage\.php/ && !/192\.168\.[0-9.]+/' access.log access.log.[0-9]    
zcat access.log*.gz | awk '/\/mypage\.php/ && !/192\.168\.[0-9.]+/'
```

Comment: Great point; added this in an edit. Thanks! :) Yes, I meant `+`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, I like this two, I accepted the first answer however as that is just smaller. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, no problem. I like the answer you accepted better too; I didn't realize that zgrep worked on non-gzipped files!